# How to ignore timeouts in ab (apache bench)?

Tags: benchmarking, load-testing, apachebench

I run benchmarks with apache bench on a web service. I know that 1-2 requests from the test will be timeouted during measurement (it's a web framework issue). And when timeout occurs `ab` quits with the message `apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)` and does not show results. I want to get measurement results ignoring these timeouted tests (or count them too, but just use timeout value as response time). Is it possible with `ab`?

EDIT: The command I use is

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost:80
```

I looked into `ab` source and from what I saw it's impossible to ignore these errors. Maybe there is a fork which implements such feature?

Comment: Share the command you using

Comment: @Adnan: I added a command

Comment: Try to use the parameter `-k` & `-r` parameters with the command.

Comment: See [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) documentation for detail.

Comment: @Adran I tried options `-r` it does not help. I do not want to benchmark keepalive connections, by the way `-k` option does not work too

Comment: @SergeyZhukov were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @amit_saxena I switched benchmarking to `wrk` tool, I did not change `ab` sources (the only way) to avoid this issue

Answer (score 6):

The default timeout is 30 seconds.  You can change this with `-s`:

```
ab -s 9999 -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost:80
```

Comment: The question was not about how to change timeout value, it was about how to ignore timeouts, proceed benchmarking and get results even if timeout occures

Comment: Good point; I misinterpreted the question.  `-s` might be an effective workaround in this situation.